# How to use same generated ID in two fields prisma-graphql

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm implementing a graphql prisma datamodel. Here I have a type called `BankAccount` . I may need to update and delete them as well. I'm implementing this as immutable object. So, when updating I'm adding updating the existing record as **IsDeleted** and add a new record. And when updating an existing record I need to keep the id of the previous record to know which record is updated. So, I've came up with a type like this

```
type BankAccount {
  id: ID! @unique
  parentbankAccount: String!
  bankName: String!
  bankAccountNo: String!
  isDeleted: Boolean! @default(value: "false")
}
```

Here the `parentBankAccount` keeps the **id** of previous `BankAccount`. I'm thinking when *creating* a bank account, setting the `parentBankAccount` as same as the `id` as it doesn't have a parent. The thing is I'm not sure it's possible. I'm bit new to GraphQL. So, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GraphQL, generally if one object refers to another, you should directly refer to that object; you wouldn't embed its ID.  You can also make fields nullable, to support the case where some relationship just doesn't exist.  For this specific field, then, this would look like

```
type BankAccount {
  parentBankAccount: BankAccount
  ...
}
```

and that field would be `null` whenever an account doesn't have a parent.

---

At an API level, the layout you describe seems a little weird.  If I call

```
query MyBankAccount {
  me { accounts { id } }
}
```

I'll get back some unique ID.  I'd be a little surprised to later call

```
query MyBalance($id: ID!) {
  node(id: $id) {
    ... on BankAccount {
      name
      isDeleted
      balance
    }
  }
}
```

and find out that my account has been "deleted" and that the balance is from a week ago.

Using immutable objects in the underlying data store makes some sense, particularly for auditability reasons, but that tends to not be something you can expose out through a GraphQL API directly (or most other API layers: this would be equally surprising in a REST framework where the object URL is supposed to be permanent).